# How to uninstall/remove Visual Studio SP1

Tags: uninstallation, visual-studio-2010

I have Windows 7 64-bit with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and subsequent installation of SP1.

If I open up Control Panels | Programs and Features, I see 3 entries for Visual Studio 2010, the third being one ADO.Net.

I tried to uninstall SP1 first and somehow that failed.  It asked for the Visual Studio 2010 setup disk, which I put in.  Sadly, after the completion, SP1 stayed in the Programs and Features list.

I tried uninstalling VS2010, which uninstalled nicely, but left the entry for SP1.  I tried uninstalling SP1, but got a message that I had to have VS2010 installed, so I bit my lip, shoveled down my irritation, and reinstalled VS2010.  I received only one option to install SP1, which I did.  I guess you can consider that a reapply.

A refresh of Programs and Features showed once again 3 entries.  I was able to uninstall SP1, at least the option was there and I was able to complete the uninstall.  I kept the VS2010 disk in the CD tray.  Sadly, closing Control Panel Programs and Features (CPPF subsequently) and reopening it, nicely showed Microsoft's bug invested SP1.  Selecting to uninstall/change the entry results in a dialog to install SP1.

It appears that SP1 might be gone in part, but obviously not entirely.  The entry, the executable/DLL tied to that entry is nicely there.

How do I remove/cleanup/delete/nuke VS2010 SP1 inclusive of CPPF and any other trash that it installed?

Comment: It would help if you would explain why you want to uninstall SP1. Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I want to get rid of Visual Studio 2010.  VS2010 SP1 appears as a separate line item.  The removal of VS2010 without removing SP1 first leaves SP1 installed but no VS2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As life moves on, I chose a chose maybe not the best solution, but it is a solution, so here is what I did.

I found an article, which  talked about removing the entry from Control Panel | Programs and Features.  http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1179.  I then did other steps.

First from the link as I have a Windows 7 64-bit system, I went to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

in the registry.  There were two locations, one the obvious with the name completely spelled out and the other with the DisplayName property set to the product name as part of a GUIID.  I deleted both entries.  The main entry with the nice name as the key was the one that deletes the program ID entry from the list.

I noticed that several products share the same InstallSource.  That is bizarro (Smallville rocks and sadly ended), all in the C:\Windows\TEMP folder.  As the actual setup program is under ProgramData folder, I am not sure what the TEMP folder entries do.

I deleted the ProgramData portion but left the C:\Windows\TEMP, although I am still thinking of cleaning that up, just am cautious.

I then deleted all other VS2010 components leaving the runtime.  By the way, do not forget to delete Premptive's expensive and end user install based pricing product.  That is further up (name sort ascending) under Dotfuscator...

That more or less cleaned things up.  I am not sure what uses the VS2010 runtime, so I am leaving that.  I assume that is what is installed at the VS2010 folder.

A side comment:  I still find it strange that Microsoft in the registry follows a ...\Software\Microsoft\ entry.  They do not follow that anywhere else.  Why there?

Details:
In the registry, the information was:

{5AB7D739-1735-3A9E-BE73-C43507CB4E6F}
    Uninstall String: MsiExec.exe /X{5AB7D739-1735-3A9E-BE73-C43507CB4E6F}
    Install Source: C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\
    InstallLocation: C:\ProgramData\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache\
    Uninstall Path: C:\ProgramData\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache\
    Uinstall String: C:\ProgramData\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache\Setup.exe

Shared products using C:\Windows\TEMP...40219 folder:
   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project
   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects
   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service
   Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
   Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Runtime - 10.0.40219
   Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime

Paths used by other products:

C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\
C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\Dotfuscator\

2 of several keys that share the same C:\Windows\TEMP folder entry (InstallSource):
InstallSource
    {09C52940-A4D1-4409-A7CC-1AAE630CF578}
    {1AA5BD63-6614-44B2-88A7-605191EDB835}

Answer (score 59):

I just ran the web installer for VS2010 SP 1 with the following parameters. That forced it to uninstall and got me past the blocking issue:

VS10sp1-KB983509.exe /uninstall /force

Comment: this solution is to be preferred over manual registry manipulation

Comment: +1 This worked for me. I had to download the installer first from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23691 but  it's less than 1MB.

Comment: Thanks james and jason for pointing me to the installer since I also couldn't find it on my system.

Comment: Did not work for me. It did try with `/force`, which avoided outright refusal to do anything, but in the end result was, "does not apply' or something like that. Oh well.

Comment: The download isn't available any more, but I had success running the cached Setup.exe at `C:\ProgramData\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache\Setup.exe` with the same `/uninstall /force` arguments as in the original question.

Answer (score 12):

I tried James solution above but it still didn't work and kept requiring the installation CD.
After further search I found this solution that worked for me:

[Microsoft tool to remove Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility.aspx)

Comment: This was the first solution to work for me. I was getting prompted to insert a non-existant source CD, with "Network location not available". Kudos to Microsoft for providing this tool. No need to muck around in the registry.

Comment: This only uninstalled VS2010 leaving the SP1 on my computer so now I have to re-install VS2010 in order to have a chance to uninstall SP1... Great...

Answer (score 2):

This answer on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98dfa323-323d-4ecd-a955-fd0014dec92e/uninstalling-visual-studio-2010) explains a sequence for manual removal, but more importantly it also links to a Microsoft FixIt [VS2010 Uninstall Utility](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=150979) which was the only way I was able to get rid of SP1.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here worked for me to remove VS 2010 SP1.
The visual stiduio 2010 uninstall utility worked  nicely to remove everything but VS 2010 SP1.

to remove SP1 I went to the setup cache and ran setup as follows:
C:\ProgramData\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache>setup /uninstall /force

Comment: This is it exactly. (Even though the entry stays in the `Program and Features`)